# Persistent name of USB serial device with Python pyserial

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, pyserial

I have a Python application that chose serial device using [pyserial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#module-serial.tools.list_ports) `serial.tools.list_ports`

I have two USB to RS485 serial adapter connected. They won't be disconnected from the server and the server has never been restarted (it's a Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS)

For some reason every time I chose to use one of the two serial, it randomly pick one even if I always choose, for istance, `/dev/ttyUSB0`

To me, it looks strange because, the server is never restarted and the USB device is never removed from it so, technically, if I use the serial port mapped to `/dev/ttyUSB0` it should always be the same

Is there a way to name serial ports in a persistent way?

Comment: Does your system create `/dev/serial/by-id/` and `/dev/serial/by-path/` for adapters? You can use symlinks from there. If it doesn't, you can write custom udev rule which creates symlinks with pre-defined names based on either device serial string or USB port id.

Comment: @dimich how can I check if it creates them?

Comment: Check if they exist when adapter is plugged.

Comment: @dimich I can see it creates both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to check the actual serial number of the USBs attached with

```
sudo lsusb -v | grep 'idVendor\|idProduct\|iSerial'
```

Then you need to create the file with

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-serial.rules
```

And add the USB you need with

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="FTZ5X8NG", SYMLINK+="USB-0"
```

where `ATTRS{serial}=="FTZ5X8NG"` is the unique identifier of the USB and `SYMLINK+="USB-0"` is the unique name you would like to give to it